# Generating a static site from a Rails app's controllers for S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

Is there a gem/preferred procedure for generating static pages from an otherwise typical Rails site? What I do now is write a messy Rake task that iterates through a set of paths/routes and wgets and saves them as static HTML.

For S3, each route, such as **controller/route_name** is saved as: **controller/route_name/index.html**

Which seems easy enough...but I end up re-writing this kind of  task over and over. I was wondering if there was a Jekkyl-like gem, but for a generic Rails configuration

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question that you need to answer is, why are you using rails if this isn't a dynamic site and can be replicated with static HTML. My opinion is that this is overkill. I'd suggest using something like [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), which allows you to write in Ruby still, with most of Rails cool-ness but with the specific purpose of exporting to static site.

Probably of little use to you if you already have the Rails site, but it's worth considering for any new projects of this nature you do.

Comment: Well, I want Rails for activerecord, MVC, and route handling. The site is static in as much as it is updated very infrequently, thus, why not just bake it out and save on server costs?